# Should I upgrade from my Fuji X100T to an X-T2?

Tags: camera-recommendation, fujifilm

I bought a Fuji X100T as it is compact, yet powerful enough for me. I'm just an amateur; and I don't have the luxury to carry around a (big) camera most of the time during the day. The Fuji X100T is a sweet spot for me, as I can carry it any time, even when I go jogging.

I am getting hungry :) I would love to get the X-T2 with 18-55 lens. I found out that I like street photography and sometimes I don't take a photo simply because I can't zoom with the X100T; i.e., I can't get close to people without them noticing me :) That would be one of the reasons for the upgrade (besides other tech benefits); at the same time, it seems that the X-T2 with this lens kit is still compact enough to be carried around - maybe I can't put it in my laptop bag, but still.

On the other hand, I can crop X100T photos and pretend it's all ok. Sure, it's not the same quality, but that's not important to me; no one will buy my photos and print. ;)

I wonder if getting an X-T2 would really make me grow and give me more abilities to express myself?

Comment: Yes. Buy them all. Every. Single. One.

Comment: Yap, @MichaelClark, thats what I am doing! I am buying also a private island to store all them there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the XT-2 kit is still a relatively compact camera/lens vs. a dSLR kit, it's still [sizably different](http://camerasize.com/compact/#566,679.359,ha,t) from an X100T. The XT-2 is more of a an SLR-style camera body, while the X100T is more of a rangefinder-style camera.

Interchangeable lenses can certainly open up more possibilities with photography, but realize that this is substantially more expensive because you'll probably end up needing multiple lenses, and because you may want to carry those lenses with you, you'll probably be graduating to some type of camera bag. The Fuji X lenses are pretty much the same size as dSLR APS-C ("crop") lenses. Also understand you'll be losing the leaf shutter and hybrid viewfinder of the X100T in the move.

Only you can say if the tradeoff in cost/portability vs. increased capability is worth it.

I would also say that *classic* street shooting is typically done with wide-to-normal lenses, the type of lens the X100T has. If you think you're conspicuous with an X100T, shooting with [a big telephoto zoom](http://camerasize.com/compact/#566,679.573,ha,t) pointed at someone can also make you very conspicuous--possibly *more* conspicuous.

Worse, it may feel even sneakier/less personal using one; more paparazzi-like/spying on and less street photographer/observing. A telephoto zoom, used from a distance, can eliminate the background context of your subjects, and may remove the "street" from your street photography. You have to take care to avoid that, if you're planning on using a longer lens for compression.  Street photography can be done with a telephoto, but it's not necessarily an easy way out of avoiding looking your subjects in the eye.